# How can I combat the laziness of the final generation in human society?

Tags: society, humans

In this world, a God known as Dea has warned the world's population of the impending rapture very early in earth's history. It has been well known from the begining of recorded history that the rapture would occur 100, 000 years from now on an exact date. During that time period, certain signs and events occur with no doubt that they come from God to slowly lead up to the final days as a reminder, and have been well documented. Now, we are within the last 1000 years of this world's cycle, in which humans both living and dead will be absorbed by God and the world will be set. The final generations of this period will live to witness the last millenia of this cycle.

Humans have an average lifespan of about 200 years. Most people go through life wanting to leave some kind of impact, in order for them to be remembered. Some want to leave an important legacy of achievement, so their names and accomplishments won't be forgotten. Others want to make a better future for their children so that they can enjoy a better life than they did. Whatever the reason, it serves as a motivator for us to leave something behind to say that we were here.

However, knowing exactly when the world will end and the moment of your death changes things. The final generation understand that their legacy will be non-existent after the world resets. The next version of humanity will have no knowledge of them, making whatever their achievements were pointless. Their memory and history of their world will become irrelevant, as if they never existed.This will become more pronounced the closer you get to the final date. Everyday will be a party, filled with orgies, drugs, and drunken debauchery to celebrate the end of the world. (We are all going to die anyway, why not go out with a bang? It is better to burn out than fade away afterall). Or fatalistic, anti-social behavior that leads to chaos and anarchy.

Now we have reached the final generation of the planet, who will live to see the last days of the world before the reset.The goal is to keep society running as smoothly as possible, without any disruptions, either by nihilistic attitudes or lecherous activities. People should go on as normal as possible until the apocalypse, where they would be consumed and absorbed by God to become one with the human consciousness.

How can I accomplish this with the final generation?

Comment: What this "final rupture" is expected to look like? Is it anything like the "Final judgement" of Christianity? If yes, I expect to see a rush of effort in final days rather than the apathy.

Comment: Little specification - do _you_ want people to keep on living normal lives, or does Dea want them to keep on living normal lives? That does change things...

Comment: If you want people to "not care" that everyone they know, love or hate will die, including themselves, on a specific day in the near future, but instead carry on as usual, then the only way is that they do not believe in it. Otherwise everyone would have *some* sort of reaction to the information, be it abandoning responsibilities, fight or denial.

Answer (score 5):

You are twenty and you are told that your newborn child will be consumed like a piece of meat in 10 years...

Parents have been known to kill people for looking wrong at their children. In their estimation their only hope is to prevent or delay this rapture. Doubtlessly these parents will be developing the strongest, nastiest god slaying weapons that they can possibly devise.

The other camp of parents who want to become one with god will be doing everything they possibly can to be judged worthy. This would include making their kids as worthy as possible too.

Depending on the mix of belief in the population, this could easily lead to civil war. Or it could lead to a dystopia were no one is allowed to be unhappy. Or it could lead to a Spartan society prepared to go down fighting.

---

You are ten years old and you are told that in five years you will be dead. You are told that your only hope of enduring past that point is to have lead a virtuous life - contributing in someway. But you are ten and your ability to do anything unmoderated by your parents is somewhere around zero.

Your only hope lies in doing something constructive. You drop out of school, emancipate yourself and spend the next five years doing the most virtuous thing you can imagine.

Alternately because you are only ten, you become hyper depressed and suicide. Afterall it doesn't mater what you do in those five years, you are going to hell through no fault of your own, simply because you only had 15 years max. Your only choice left is to decide how you are going to die.

---

The only people doing nothing at all are those who do not believe that anything they do will make their future any better.

The only people leading their lives normally are those who do not believe that this rapture will happen at all.

---

Your only hope to keep society running normally is to not have it informed of this rapture.

Either because it was genuinely lost in the sands of time, or have it actively disbelieved as anything more than some ancient story written on crumbling stone.

Comment: I expect a fair number of suicides, unless deity has taken that option off the table.

Comment: *unless deity has taken that option off the table*... In which case no one who wants to die can die at all... **That already sounds like hell**. More importantly that means that there are no repercussions for walking around shooting and blowing everything up. Even if their morals prevented such actions, much of the apparatus called the brain is there to keep us alive. If you cannot die, much of what we call human behaviour is no longer relevant, you will be alive regardless. That will drive many to deep melancholy, only perpetuating the nihilism.

Comment: By “take it off the table”, I just meant “you’ll be damned if you do.”

Comment: Fair enough. But that still leaves the person who believes that they are already damned. There is nothing left to lose here.

Answer (score 3):

## Spread the Heresy

Deny the teachings of the goddess. Those signs confirming the end is near? Actually Banjo the sock-puppet god had said those were the signs that the world would be ok forever. He also said that a thousand years before Deaism was invented. It is written in a book and also said by many people in the internets, so it must be true. Also Banjo says I'm perfect just the way I am and every mistake I make is not my fault but the devil's, so I want his account of the signs to be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

**Give everyone superpowers and the ability to not die.**

Have the weekend for the last several decades be like a wacky free-mode from a video game where physics is all messed up and the points don't matter. Everything resets to a Pre-saturday state on Monday.

TGIF never sounded so good.